# When developing a cross platform app using capacitor, should I develop it with Ionic or just Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

There is one software I like to build, which should later run as a web app, an android app, iOS and maybe desktop app as well. Capacitor promises to enable that using only one code base. Now I am about to start coding and wonder if I either start this as an Ionic4 + Angular project or just as an Angular project.

The app will be mainly used in the web and on a smartphone. Both platforms important.

Answer (score 1):

That’s up to you, Capacitor works with any framework or no framework at all.
Also Ionic 4 can be used with most popular frameworks too, not just Angular.

Comment: Thank you. I can work with both Ionic and Angular quite well. But I wonder if the UI in the web will look as I want it to when I develop mainly in Ionic (+Angular). Or vice versa. So that's why I am wondering with which framework I should start with.